# Need help sorting list of objects by key

Tags: python, list, sorting, key, genetic-algorithm

I am unable to get this code to sort a list of objects using either .sort() or sorted().  What am I missing here?

P.S. My solution.distance() method could use some cosmetic surgery too if anyone has any suggestions.

Thanks!

```
import random
import math

POPULATION_SIZE = 100

data = [[1, 565.0, 575.0],
        [2, 25.0, 185.0],
        [3, 345.0, 750.0],
        [4, 945.0, 685.0],
        [5, 845.0, 655.0],
        [6, 880.0, 660.0],
        [7, 25.0, 230.0],
        [8, 525.0, 1000.0],
        [9, 580.0, 1175.0],
        [10, 650.0, 1130.0]
        ]

class Solution():

  def __init__(self):
    self.dna = []
    self.randomize()

  def randomize(self):
    temp = data[:]
    while len(temp) > 0:
      self.dna.append( temp.pop( random.randint( 0,len(temp)-1 ) ) ) 

  def distance(self): 
    total = 0 
    #There has to be a better way to access two adjacent elements.
    for i, points in enumerate(self.dna):
      if i < (len(self.dna)-1): 
        total += math.sqrt( (points[1]-self.dna[i+1][1])**2 + (points[2]-self.dna[i+1][2])**2 )
      else:
        total += math.sqrt( (points[1]-self.dna[0][1])**2 + (points[2]-self.dna[0][2])**2 )
    return int(total)


class Population():

  def __init__(self):
    self.solutions = []
    self.generation = 0

    #Populate with solutions
    self.solutions = [Solution() for i in range(POPULATION_SIZE)]


  def __str__(self):

    result = ''

    #This is the part that is not returning sorted results.  I tried sorted() too.
    self.solutions.sort(key=lambda solution: solution.distance, reverse=True)


    for solution in self.solutions:
      result += 'ID: %s - Distance: %s\n' % ( id(solution),  solution.distance() )

    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':

  p = Population()
  print p
```

Comment: A little more explanation of what you're trying to achieve would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
key=lambda solution: solution.distance
```

to

```
key=lambda solution: solution.distance()
```

(The parentheses are needed to call the function.)

Alternatively, you could make the `distance` method a property:

```
  @property
  def distance(self): 
      ....
```

In this case, change all occurances of `solution.distance()` to `solution.distance`. I think this alternate solution is a little bit nicer, since it removes two characters of clutter (the parens) every time you wish to talk about the distance.

PS. `key=lambda solution: solution.distance` was returning the bound method `solution.distance` for each `solution` in `self.solutions`. Since the same object was being returned as the key for each `solution`, no desired ordering occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at cleaning up your class, using functional programming techniques:

```
import random

class Solution():

  def __init__(self):
    self.dna = []
    self.randomize()

  def randomize(self):
    self.dna = data
    random.shuffle(self.dna)

  def distance(self):
    # Return the distance between two points.
    def point_distance((p1, p2)):
      return math.sqrt((p1[1]-p2[1])**2) + (p1[2]-p2[2])**2)
    # sums the distances between consecutive points.
    # zip pairs consecutive points together, wrapping around at end.
    return int(sum(map(point_distance, zip(self.dna, self.dna[1:]+self.dna[0:1])))
```

This is untested, but should be close to working.  Also, a suggestion would be to use a class instead of a 3-element list for data.  It will make your code much clearer to read:

```
   def point_distance((p1, p2)):
      return math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)**2) + (p1.y-p2.y)**2)
```

Comment: You need `self.dna` in the last line

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way to write the loop in `distance()`: put the following function definition, taken from the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), in your code:

```
from itertools import izip, tee
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Then you can write `distance` to take advantage of Python's efficient iterator manipulation routines, like so:

```
from itertools import chain, islice
def distance(self): 
    all_pairs = islice(pairwise(chain(self.dna, self.dna)), 0, len(self.dna))
    return sum(math.sqrt((p[1]-q[1])**2 + (p[2]-q[2])**2) for p,q in all_pairs)
```

This should be reasonably efficient even if the `dna` array is very long.

Comment: I think pairwise doesn't circularly wrap around the array (which, if I can tell from the code, is what the OP wants)

Comment: That's why I used `chain` to basically concatenate two copies of the array. The `islice(pairwise(chain(...)))` construction will (should) iterate over `(a[0],a[1]),(a[1],a[2]),...,(a[N-1],a[0])`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to try this out and do some performance testing.  :)